# ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty

I am trying to connect a BeagleBone board to my system, via ssh connection. When I am giving the `ssh debian@192.168.7.2` command in terminal, I am getting the `ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host` error, but I am able to connect through PuTTY. I am having this problem only while connecting through [ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsLbh.png).

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

[ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RCaI.png)

[ssh -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5eOs.png)[ssh -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGc1Q.png)

[after re-naming /.ssh/config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Vx2.png)

[grep -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh2Cy.png)

Comment: Try the `ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2` command to get more detailed information about the connection problem.

Comment: Please, paste terminal output as text and **not as a screenshot image**.

Comment: Thankyou for the replay, I tried the ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2,and I attched the result in above question,what mistake I am doing not getting..

Comment: sorry ,for some of the reason I am not able to login in my linux system so I am attching the screenshot..

Comment: I don't think your second screenshot is the full output of `ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2`.  The command has not returned to the shell prompt. Are the last lines missing?

Comment: yes the last line is,/bin/bash : error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6:failed to map segment from shared object....ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remost host.

Comment: your suggestions are more useful for me,replay me guys please...

Comment: Is your system fully up-to-date? Can you test once more (after updating your system) the `ssh -v ...` command and paste the full (or the last lines) of the command's output?

Comment: the os version is 4.9.0-9-amd64

Comment: thankyou for the replay,I attached the ssh -v debian@192.168.6.2 output in above question..

Comment: I cannot see the message `error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6:...` in the last screenshot. However there is a message like `Executing proxy command:...` Are you really using a proxy or is something left in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file? Can you rename the file `$HOME/.ssh/config` (if present)  and retry?

Comment: I renamed the $HOME/.ssh/config file and retried again ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2,I attached the output in above question..

Comment: when I am trying "ssh debian@192.168.7.2" ,I am getting /bin/bash:error while loading shared libraries:libc.so.6:failed to map segment from shared object.

Comment: how to proceed next,I am waiting for your suggestions sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a `ProxyCommand` configuration directive enabled by mistake in your system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file.

You should edit this file with **root access**. I suggest using the `sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config` text editing command to put a comment (the character `#`) in front of the line number 19 that contains the string `ProxyCommand`. I am assuming that your current user (`beagle`) has `sudo` privilege allowing you to do this.

If you are not comfortable with the `vi` command, you can use the graphical `gedit` text editor. The following command may be used to open the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
$ xhost +
$ sudo gedit /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

---

If you have still problems updating the system-wide configuration file, please try this:

```
$ sed 's/ProxyCommand/# ProxyCommand/' /etc/ssh/ssh_config >/tmp/1
$ diff /etc/ssh/ssh_config /tmp/1
```

Inspect `diff` command output and verify that the update is OK; then copy the temporary file over the system-wide configuration file:

```
$ sudo cat /tmp/1 >/etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment: Thankyou for the replay,I comment the 19th line in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file,after that restarted the ssh and tried the "ssh debian@192.168.7.2" but again I am facing the same problem

Comment: Please, post `grep -i proxycomm /etc/ssh/ssh_config $HOME/.ssh/*` output. And also refresh `ssh -v ...` output.

Comment: /etc/ssh/ssh_config file 19th line is Host * ,I commented that one,and grep -i proxycomm  /etc/ssh/ssh_config $HOME/.ssh/* result attched in above question and ssh -v debian@192.168.7.2 output also attached but its not completed the system is strucked or hanged(I waited upto 25 minutes).

Comment: It is obvious that you haven't been able to comment out the line containing `ProxyCommand`

Comment: means I have to comment proxy command?

Comment: I updated my answer with an easier way to update the configuration file.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir ,just I comment the proxy command ,now I am able to login beaglebone via ssh..

Comment: @Asha If this solved your problem, you should accept it as a solution. Please, click both the "check mark" and the "upper triangle" on the left of my answer.

Comment: ok Sir,but have one small doubt ,proxy command is used to connect to the server right,while commenting that proxy command I am able to login ,how its possible?.. asking just for information(to understand).

Comment: Proxycommand is used for specifying an intermediary server (TCP node) when there is no direct TCP connection between the ssh client and the ssh server. If you google `ssh proxycommand` you will find explanations on this.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.